# Karate Framework - How to verify the value in the response from array based on certain unique id?

Tags: karate

There is a requirement to verify the value in response based on some unique id e.g.

```
{
  "type": "Manual",
  reading: [
    {
      "id": 123123244,
      foodReading: {
        "value": 10,
        "unit": "g"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 133323244,
      foodReading: {
        "value": 17,
        "unit": "g"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In above response I need to verify that the id `133323244` value is `17` using Karate assertions. What should be an approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter method.

```
 * def jsonRequest =
        """
        {
      "type": "Manual",
      reading: [
        {
          "id": 123123244,
          foodReading: {
            "value": 10,
            "unit": "g"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 133323244,
          foodReading: {
            "value": 17,
            "unit": "g"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
        """

* def expectedValue = 17
* def actualValue = jsonRequest.reading.filter((item)=>item.id == '133323244')[0].foodReading.value
Then match expectedValue == actualValue
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shreyansh both answers are working.

Answer (score 1):

This is just one way to do it, please read through the documentation and examples for more:

```
* match response.reading contains deep { id: 123123244, foodReading: { value: 10 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Karate.jsonPath as well. Below is the solution.

```
  * def jsonRequest =
    """
    {
  "type": "Manual",
  reading: [
    {
      "id": 123123244,
      foodReading: {
        "value": 10,
        "unit": "g"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 133323244,
      foodReading: {
        "value": 17,
        "unit": "g"
      }
    }
  ]
}
    """
* def expectedValue = 17
* def data =  karate.jsonPath(jsonRequest,"$.reading[?(@.id == '133323244')]")[0].foodReading.value
Then match expectedValue == data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use find() as well. Below code will work too.

```
 * def expectedValue = 17
    * def actualValue = jsonRequest.reading.find(x => x.id == '133323244').foodReading.value
    Then match expectedValue == actualValue
```